# AutoSuggest in Android from jsonencoded array of php

Tags: java, php, android, json

I want to use json encoded array which i am return from this link :
http://sids.roundone.asia/suggest.json?data=soft
as suggestions in android application.

(I have used json_encode($arr) function in php file and i am returning that as response for above link)

I have a problem in reading this response in java and storing it in an `ArrayList`.

My code is :

```
 try {
        String temp=sName.replace(" ", "%20");
        URL js = new URL("https://sids.roundone.asia/suggest.json?data="+temp);
        URLConnection jc = js.openConnection();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(jc.getInputStream()));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(line);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("results");
        for(int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.length(); i++){
            JSONObject r = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            ListData.add(new SuggestGetSet(jsonResponse.get(String.vlaueOf(iss)));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I could see on your link, you're returning a JSON Array, instead of a JSON Object, ( "[ ]" instead of "{ }") and then in your java code you're trying to create a `JSONObject` here:

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(line);
```

Try changing that to:

```
JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONArray(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

You return JSON array directly not a JSON Object have inner array so cast your incoming response to **JSONArray** directly.

```
JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONArray(line);
```